# How to convert day to Year-Month-Day format with T-SQL in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have an int field (Days) in myTable. How can I format it to Year-Month-Day String?

I want to do this with T-SQL SQL Server 2008.

For example:

65 Days = 0 Year 2 Month 5 Day

Comment: Does 65 denote the 65th day of the year (which year), than it is solvable. A general conversion of a duration into years-month-days can't be exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "zero" here is 01 Jan 1900. This gives a date related to this

```
SELECT
   dateadd(day, myColumn, 0)
FROM
   myTable
```

If you want to break out the component values separately

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
     dateadd(day, myColumn, 0) AS theDate 
  FROM
     myTable
)
SELECT
  DATEPART(year, theDate) - 1900,
  DATEPART(month, theDate),
  DATEPART(day, theDate)
FROM
  CTE
```

Then you also have the leap year issues. After 28 Feb 1904, you have 29 Feb 1904 There isn't a 100% guaranteed way to express "days" as years + months + days because month lengths very every 4 years or so.

In case I've misunderstood, to rebase it to year "zero"

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '0001-01-01', 0), CAST(DATEADD(day, myColumn, 1) as date))
FROM
   myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @days int
set @days = 65
select 
cast(year(dateadd(day,@days,0))-1900 as varchar) + ' Year '
+ cast(month(dateadd(day,@days,0)) as varchar) + ' Month '
+ cast(day(dateadd(day,@days,0)) as varchar) + ' Day'
```

Keep in mind that this is measured from 1st of junuari and other problems

Answer (score -2):

I got to this code...

```
select
cast((DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate()))as CHAR(3)) +'years '+
case when (datediff(DAY,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte), getdate()),
DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte)),GETDATE()))<0 
then
cast(DATEDIFF(month,DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte), getdate()) -1 AS CHAR(2))
else 
cast (DATEDIFF(month,DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte), getdate())AS CHAR(2))
end +'months '+
-------------------------------------------
case when (datediff(DAY,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte), getdate()),
DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte)),GETDATE()))<0
then
cast(datediff(DAY,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte), getdate())-1,
DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte)),GETDATE()) as CHar(2))
else
cast(datediff(DAY,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte), getdate()),
DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte)),GETDATE())as Char(2))
end+'days' as
Lenghtofservice
--DATEADD(year,(DATEDIFF(year, StartDate, getdate())),StartDAte)) 
 from dbo.Employee
```